# What is the use of VmWare Virtual network adapters

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, network-adapter

I had VmWare Workstation for times ago and one day I noticed that my laptop is not going to shutdown or hibernate or sleep normally and it got stock turned on and with screen turned off which I had to hold the poweroff button to get it shutdown manually.

After some struggle I found out that the problem was from VmWare's Virtual Network Adapters and when I disabled those (there were 2) my problem was gone til now. At that time I thought that any VM will not have network connectivity since then but they do have using a process called `vmnat.exe` .

Can disabling these adapters cause problem to VM's connectivity? What are those used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will not have any problems because as I know those adapters are used to give your VM an IP address only and nothing else. The base work is done by that process you have mentioned (VmNat.exe) which stands at very low level of system and does mirroring processes .
So go ahead, No problem will occur in future.